# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null Google Map Json Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null when trying to return json data as markers for my Google map. What am I doing wrong because `console.log(data);` returns my data so I know that's fine.

```
 function initialize() {

    var latitude = -23.92175976307374,
        longitude = 24.120724868774414,
        center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
        mapOptions = {
                center: center,
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_branches"), mapOptions);

        setMarkers(center, map);

        function setMarkers(center, map) {
        var json = (function () { 
            var json = null; 
            $.ajax({ 
                'dataType': "json",
                'url': "/data/supplier_branches/",                  
                'success': function (data) {
                     json = data; 
                 console.log(data);
                 }
            });
            return json;
        })();

        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
            var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.info
                });
                infoBranch(map, marker, data);
            }
        }

         function infoBranch(map, marker, data) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        // Attaching a click event to the current marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.title+data.info);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });

         // Creating a closure to retain the correct data 
        // Note how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
        (function(marker, data) {
          // Attaching a click event to the current marker
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        })(marker, data);
    }

    };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: i HOPE YOU CAN'T GET JSON LENGTH DIRECTLY RATHER YOU CAN GET LIKE VAR DATA =eval('(' + data+ ')'); DATA.length(); THIS MEANS YOU HAVE TO EVAL THE JSON STRING INTO OBJECTS

Comment: And my doubt once you used  return json; your data may return and that function is completed it will not do anythign else

Comment: Does `eval('(' + data+ ')'); DATA.length();` replace `json[i]`

Comment: Did not work, but thanks

Comment: @AntoKing when I tried this again I got: `756 : CS -> BG : FAILED closepopuptoplevel` in the console. If my json data looks like this `{ 
  "title": "title",
  "info": "infoz",
  "lat": "-25.333",
  "lng": "152.007"
}`  How do I make that into a json string/js object

Answer (score 0):

you variable **json** is defined inside your ajax call, so try `window.json = data;` to be able to use it in other functions.

also worth mentioning that after that you need to put `window.` before all the `json` variables whenever you want to use it. e.g. `window.json.length`

Comment: Simply changing `json = data;` to `window.json = data;` as well as all the `json` variables after does not work. Am I missing a step?

Comment: what is the error you're getting? have you checked your console (pressing F12) for any signs of error? also check to see if **data** in your ajax call returns the desired value and let me know how it goes

Comment: Yes the json data returns what I need but its not usin the lat and lng values as co-ordinates. At the line `for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {` it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null